# How to get suspend mode working?

Tags: 12.04, suspend

I have a Sony Vaio VPCF11C5E notebook and Ubuntu 12.04, but my suspend mode is not working.
Every time when I try to start the suspension mode, the notebook goes into the suspension mode. When I try to wake the notebook up, it does a normal start.

Does anybody have an idea what I can do to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following wiki page is a good place to start to debug this issue: 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend