# 13.04 black screen when waking up from suspend

Tags: 13.04, suspend

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Lenovo g580.

When running pm-suspend or closing the lid, the laptop suspends just fine. However when I re-open the lid or press a button, it wakes up (fans start running), the screen remains all black (no mouse pointer or anything) and I am forced to reboot.

Sometimes I can hear a sound that I think is the ubuntu login prompt, suggesting that the laptop is running and that the problem is with the monitor.

I have no full-screen applications or external devices plugged in at the time of suspend.

How can I diagnose and fix this problem?

Here is a copy of my /var/log/syslog after a reboot after a failed suspend-wakeup:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5690306

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/179892/how-to-get-suspend-mode-working?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> and after return to tty7 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (the default terminal for desktop manager) or increase brightness monitor.

Comment: That did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but with saucy (13.10). My case is weird though as I had this problem right after clean install - where I 'fixed' it with setting

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
```

in '/etc/default/grub' - following the suggestion of [Ubuntu freezes/crash after wake when upgraded to 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361547/ubuntu-freezes-crash-after-wake-when-upgraded-to-13-10) .

After installing another window-manager (I can't be certain that this was the cause of re-occurrence of the problem) I experienced the problem again, and can't seem to fix it again.

**Edit: this was not the problem - as I have stated further down, my laptop resumes perfectly with an external display. Nothing to do with the GRUB setting...**

```
    randubu
    description: Notebook
    product: P150HMx (Not Applicable)
    vendor: CLEVO
    version: Not Applicable
    serial: Not Applicable
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Not Applicable sku=Not Applicable uuid=0090F5C0-F041-0000-0000-000000000000
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: P150HMx
       vendor: CLEVO
       physical id: 0
       version: Not Applicable
       serial: Not Applicable
       slot: Not Applicable
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 4.6.4
          date: 07/06/2011
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1984KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 4
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: internal varies
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 5
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: internal varies unified
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 6
          size: 6MiB
          capacity: 6MiB
          capabilities: internal varies unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 7
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: KHX1600C9S3/4GX
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: DD105B22
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 1
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
        *-bank:2
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: KHX1600C9S3/4GX
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 2
             serial: E3105D22
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM [empty]
             product: [Empty]
             vendor: [Empty]
             physical id: 3
             serial: [Empty]
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4f
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 09
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f7e00000-f7efffff ioport:e0000000(size=268435456)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Blackcomb [Radeon HD 6970M/6990M]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:54 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e20000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7e00000-f7e1ffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6800 Series]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:52 memory:f7e40000-f7e43fff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:50 memory:f7f0a000-f7f0a00f
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7f08000-f7f083ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:51 memory:f7f00000-f7f03fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7d00000-f7dfffff
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
                vendor: NEC Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 04
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:f7d00000-f7d01fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f7c00000-f7cfffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 05
                serial: 00:90:f5:c0:f0:41
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msix msi bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=jme driverversion=1.0.8 duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:53 memory:f7c20000-f7c23fff ioport:d100(size=128) ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7c10000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c00000-f7c0ffff
           *-generic:0
                description: System peripheral
                product: SD/MMC Host Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
                version: 90
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:f7c26000-f7c260ff
           *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
                description: SD Host controller
                product: Standard SD Host Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.2
                version: 90
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:f7c25000-f7c250ff
           *-generic:2
                description: System peripheral
                product: MS Host Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0.3
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.3
                version: 90
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=jmb38x_ms latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:f7c24000-f7c240ff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:f7b00000-f7bfffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 01
                serial: e0:91:53:5c:36:8d
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.11.0-15-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.30.84.63 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:18 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7b00000-f7b03fff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 memory:f7a00000-f7afffff
           *-firewire
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: IEEE 1394 Host Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                version: 30
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=0
                resources: irq:19 memory:f7a01000-f7a017ff memory:f7a00000-f7a000ff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7f07000-f7f073ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:49 ioport:f070(size=8) ioport:f060(size=4) ioport:f050(size=8) ioport:f040(size=4) ioport:f020(size=32) memory:f7f06000-f7f067ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7f05000-f7f050ff ioport:f000(size=32)
```

** / text cutout because of need of space for post / **

The window manager was StumpWM, but the problem occurs also from within standard Ubuntu environment. I both tried the standard fglrx and the fglrx-updates drivers.

**Edit:**
*My system (as the original authers) does actually get into Ubuntu when resuming from suspend; just with a black screen. Here I've been able to either run 'shutdown -h now' or the REISUB combination to restart.

If I run a script after resumation to only show output on my laptops display (which works when not having suspended prior) - this has no effect.

Weirdly enough - if I attach an external monitor to my laptop through HDMI before suspending, my computer resumes the display perfectly, but only on the external display... The laptops own display will still not show any output until restart.

The last record of the '/var/log/pm-suspend.log':*

```
Initial commandline parameters: 
Thu Feb 13 16:14:24 CET 2014: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend:
Linux randubu 3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Module                  Size  Used by
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
rfcomm                 69130  0 
bnep                   19704  2 
bluetooth             372041  10 bnep,rfcomm
binfmt_misc            17468  1 
vesafb                 13828  1 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14162  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm_intel             138567  0 
kvm                   431720  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
cryptd                 20359  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     41117  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    55704  1 
arc4                   12608  2 
microcode              23576  0 
joydev                 17377  0 
snd_hda_intel          48171  10 
rtl8192ce              53550  0 
snd_hda_codec         188738  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
rtl_pci                26641  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi                63229  2 rtl_pci,rtl8192ce
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
rtl8192c_common        48877  1 rtl8192ce
snd_pcm               102033  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
mac80211              597268  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192ce
psmouse                97655  0 
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
serio_raw              13413  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30095  1 snd_seq_midi
lpc_ich                21080  0 
cfg80211              480503  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
jmb38x_ms              18670  0 
snd_timer              29433  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
memstick               16760  1 jmb38x_ms
snd                    69141  31 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
fglrx                6732964  44 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
mei_me                 18421  0 
mei                    77782  1 mei_me
amd_iommu_v2           19054  1 fglrx
wmi                    19070  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
video                  19318  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42299  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 53014  0 
hid                   105858  2 hid_generic,usbhid
firewire_ohci          40327  0 
firewire_core          64534  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core
ahci                   25819  5 
sdhci_pci              19014  0 
libahci                31928  1 ahci
jme                    44269  0 
sdhci                  42898  1 sdhci_pci
mii                    13934  1 jme
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8154216     902912    7251304          0      71376     446516
-/+ buffers/cache:     385020    7769196
Swap:      8693756          0    8693756
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend:
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend:
stop: Unknown instance: 
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led suspend suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend:
ATI Catalyst driver detected, not using quirks.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.

Thu Feb 13 16:14:25 CET 2014: performing suspend
Thu Feb 13 16:14:36 CET 2014: Awake.
Thu Feb 13 16:14:36 CET 2014: Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend:
Reloaded unloaded modules.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.

Thu Feb 13 16:14:37 CET 2014: Finished.
```

I will try to install the latest Catalyst driver from their site as my next step, as I need 3D acceleration on my laptop.. (argument for not installing the open-source driver)

Answer (score -2):

I had this problem as well.  Very frustrating.  I started using fgrlx-updates driver.  This has fixed the problem for me.  This can be found in Software & Updates and then Additional Drivers.  I stopped using Ubuntu for a while because of this, but I'm glad I found this fix.  Hope it works for you.

Comment: This answer does not apply to this question as the Lenovo G580 only comes with Intel and NVIDIA graphics, not AMD/ATI.