# Ubuntu freezes/crash after wake when upgraded to 13.10

Tags: suspend

Back on 13.04 it didn't occurred.
I've upgraded to 13.10, systems apparently working fine, but, when I put it to sleep(using or not using extended monitor) and try to wake up, I see the screen(both), without lock-screen, but completely freeze, Neither `tty` open, nor the keyboard works.

So, only option remains is to force shut-down.
Any clue how to investigate the cause or fix it?
Thanks in advance, any info that'll help you could ask!

```
Ubuntu 13.10 x64 - not a fresh install/upgraded - with Unity
Dell Vostro 3550
AMD Proprietary Drivers - 13.11 / Hybrid with Intel
```

--------------------- EDIT ------------------------

The fix has gone, i cant wake from suspend again, and, every time i shutdown/power up, i got like 9 windows from "report problem".
this is the error:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you use gnome 3?

Comment: Unity, fix below provided by @Saurav

Comment: This is still happening in 14.04...

Answer (score 11):

**Actually there is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/781402) which you can find in [Launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/)**

Best thing is that there is also a patch through which you can solve this issue.

Follow these steps hope it works for you also:

- Open terminal and execute these steps:

  ```
  sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub_back
  ```

  <sub>taking the backup of original `/etc/default/grub` file, in case some error occurs we can get back to original state</sub>

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
  ```

  <sub>opening the file in gedit to make the changes.</sub>

  Once file opened replace following line :

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  ```

  to the line:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
  ```

  Save the file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and close <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

<sub>**Note:** The next line to the line mentioned above should be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` not `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`</sub>

- Now execute following command to update the `grub`

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Re-start your system once.

Note: If you have trouble in brightness also and above method doesn't fix it then you can test by adding these lines in place I mentioned above.

**2.** `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`

or

**3.** `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor pcie_aspm=force"`

or

**4.** `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

or

**5.** `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pcie_aspm=force"`

or

**6.** `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"`

<sub>**Note**: You have to do a `sudo update-grub` and a system restart every time you change the **grub** file</sub>

**Different system would need different options, if any of the option works, I request to mention that in the comment.**

Reply if something goes wrong..

Comment: I was having this issue back on 13.04, and used it on grub to fix: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux" (its my actual grub) i'll try this new config

Comment: If any of the settings helped you then I would like you to mention the line which actually fixes your issue.. It would help others also to get through their issue..

Comment: Hello saurav, ive used the: " GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"" But i got no good. With the old grub config, the system freezes with a black screen, i can move the pointer once, so it freezes. Here the video:  http://youtu.be/0kKfb2xeen4

Comment: Did you check after a system restart. If you can access your system then try to check other options also. And please note that it is necessary to do a system restart. I'm adding some more option please check it one by one.

Comment: @krustbr: And one thing I just noticed that in my grub file there is not value for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. Did you ever change your grub before and added the value like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`. Once try to remove this and do the method what I preferred you first.. I know I would be difficult and time consuming but sorry! Try all options with line option : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` which is on the 2nd line..

Comment: Its fixed! Ive tried all the options, with no success, then, i've noted i forgot to test the first option you said. So, to fix this issue i've just removed the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux` and then, put the: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"` , update-grub;reboot and it works, the screen goes black but when i type/move mouse it works to the unlock screen. Thanks @saurav

Comment: I already told you na.. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"` is looking strange to me it should be like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`. any way good to know that you finally fixed your issue. Glad to help you.. :) Now let me edit my answer and post the original which actually fixed your issue..

Comment: i've found the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"` was used on a fix to the same issue back on the 13.04, Thanks

Comment: I have Ubuntu 13.10 with Gnome and works perfect with the first option provided by @SauravKumar. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @SauravKumar i have the same problem on my hp 620, but none of the lines helped me,any ideas ???

Comment: @ArK: No idea, have you tried other answers. Also try a new **Kernel**, but be sure that you install a new kernel after removing your graphics driver and don't forget to re-install all the graphics driver.

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force" worked for me with Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In my system (Samsung Chronos 7 with hybrid graphics, using fglrx drivers because the open source ones makes the system not bootable (1)), the suspend/resume if successful only if made from a virtual console. So I had to add the file(2):

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 152 Dec  7 12:09 /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt
```

with the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Switch to a VC before suspending and back after resume

case "$1" in
        resume|thaw)
            chvt 7
        ;;
        suspend|hibernate)
            chvt 1
        ;;
esac
```

You could need this instead or in addition to [Saurav solutions](https://askubuntu.com/a/361706/16395).

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) Update: I now can use open-source drivers. [It was an overheating problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/390050/16395).

(2) Step-by-step:

1. edit/create the file

   `gksudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt`
2. copy and paste the content above
3. save and exit
4. make it executable:

   `chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt`

Answer (score 1):

When I installed fglrx on Saucy for my Radeon 6870, I experienced the same problem. I tried Saurav Kumar's method, but none of those boot parameters worked.
From [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2115441), though, I found and tried adding "**nomodeset**" as a parameter, and I was able to resume from suspend normally.

Comment: Thanks for your information, I'll add this also to one of the options in my answer. Actually different version of system acts differently and it is not sure which patch will work for particular system. :)

Answer (score 1):

Replacement of the Grub line with
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
was not enough for me.

At restart my screen resolution was downgraded and wakeup from suspend was still not working.

I had to change the video card driver from the "nouveau" (open source) to the NVidia (proprietary).

Altogether, it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I had all kind of problems with that same laptop model and the 13.11 Beta proprietary driver, which by the way, states it is for **Xorg/Xserver 6.9 and above (up to 1.13)** and Saucy has Xorg version 1.14.

Anyway, almos all of my problems went away after running:

```
$sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Hope that helps...