# Ubuntu 13.10 suspend crashes KDE / black screen on wake

Tags: kubuntu, kde, suspend, 13.10

### Setup

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10, with KDE (installed via Ubuntu server disk and sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop).

### Problem

Whenever I suspend the computer while in KDE (either via sudo pm-suspend in Konsole or via KDE's interface), I get a black screen on wake up.

### Attempted workarounds / fixes

If I press ctrl+alt+f1 and then ctrl+alt+f7 and I'm patient (20-30 seconds), I sometimes get back into KDE where I was, or sometimes I get back to the login screen (KDE crashed). But even when I get back into KDE, I get a notification saying that the special effects had to restart due to a graphics problem and then the fonts in all applications are... garbled.

**If I suspend from another tty with sudo pm-suspend (while KDE is running on tty7), it works flawlessly (resumes instantly - no need to wait 20-30 seconds, KDE does not crash and does not cause font garble).**

I tried changing graphics drivers and I get the same thing (I have Nvidia NVS300 and I'm using the latest proprietary drivers in Ubuntu repos). Also tried this [Ubuntu freezes/crash after wake when upgraded to 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361547/ubuntu-freezes-crash-after-wake-when-upgraded-to-13-10) and it didn't work.

This problem did not occur on the same system, when I was running Kubuntu 12.04.

### Trying to find the problem...

Dmesg doesn't show any errors. I don't even know where to look further for any errors (any KDE logs?). Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm having similar problems with hibernate but not suspend.  Do you also see this in hibernate?

Comment: Also, have you verified hibernate is active in your BIOS?  I never remember the BIOS terminologies my self, so you might find this page helpful: http://gsmblog.com/post/Difference-between-S1-%28POS%29-and-S3-%28STR%29-standby-mode-in-BIOS.aspx

Comment: @virtualxtc When I try to hibernate, the screen goes black but it doesn't go into hibernate (power lights don't go off and fans still spinning). But computer remains unresponsive. Looking in /var/log/pm-suspend.log (after I power cycle the computer), I see that it reports that it thaws back a few seconds after the hibernate command.

Comment: @virtualxtc My BIOS doesn't have a setting for enabling / disabling standby modes.

Comment: hum, if the solutions below don't suit your likeing you might want to play with the grub2 powermangement boot flags (acpi=on, acpi=off)  more here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this workaround. I made a script that switches to console before suspend and switches back after resume.

I put attached script into dir `/etc/pm/sleep.d`.  I gave it the name `fix-black-screen` and made it executable (`sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/fix-black-screen`).

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in
suspend)
    # Suspending to RAM.
    chvt 1
    sleep 1
;;
resume)
    # Resume from suspend.
    sleep 1
    chvt 7
;;
esac
```

Original fix found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/390828/81173).

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems to yours.

```
pm-suspend --store-quirks-as-lkw
```

Fixed my problems.

I only had to do it once, and suspending after that was working fine.

Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Pedro. It didn't help unfortunately. I get the same behaviour as before.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a machine with the latest nvidia driver and was seeing the same issue.  I found that

```
pm-suspend --quirk-save-pci
```

seems to have solved the problem.  I put it in my `/var/cache/pm-utils/last_known_working.quirkdb` file and I think it's working now.