# Xorg/nvidia crashing my 14.04 after waking up from suspend

Tags: nvidia, xorg

Ok, unfortuantely I can't copy the crash report, but it happens 1 out of 5 times after waking up from suspend and the tile is this
Xorg crashed with SIGABRTH

the executable path loeads to XORG as well

I'm with the latest nvidia drivers from the software center.
I suppose other people have the same problem since those nvidia drivers seem to be problematic. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: I am trying to fix this issue too. Please let me know if you have found any solution.

Comment: Had the same issue. This fix worked for me. You don't even have to reboot! http://askubuntu.com/questions/363111/ubuntu-13-10-suspend-crashes-kde-black-screen-on-wake?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my laptop suddenly freeze after a period of time?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/566606/why-does-my-laptop-suddenly-freeze-after-a-period-of-time)