# Laptop will not wake up after closing lid after updating to 13.10

Tags: screen, 13.10, suspend

I tried the steps at [Ubuntu freezes/crash after wake when upgraded to 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361547/ubuntu-freezes-crash-after-wake-when-upgraded-to-13-10).  None of them solved my problem.

When I close the lid on my laptop, ubuntu goes to sleep just as it always has.  However, since the update, it just shows a black screen (pixels emit leak through light, showing screen to at least have turned on.)

Sometimes (once), my desktop will flash before going into the black screen.

This is a very annoying bug, and if any more information is needed (cat insert-config-file-here, etc), I am willing to provide