# No wakeup after screenlock

Tags: unity, ati, suspend, lock-screen

After 10 minutes my desktop computer darkens the screen, and when I move the mouse or tab any key it comes back alive and asks for my password. That is perfect and the behavior I like to have it.

But sometimes (mostly after a longer period) I can't get back to the login screen.

Nothing happens when moving mouse or press a key. Only way to get the computer back working is by restarting with reset button on the machine.

Has anyone an idea what I need to do?

I have a AMD HD 7950 grapics card with the 13.12 driver.

Ubuntu is 13.10 with Unity.

Here is a link to a blogger with the same problem:

[Ubuntu Suspend Won't Wake Up: My Quest - wafflesatnoon.com](http://wafflesatnoon.com/2012/11/17/ubuntu-suspend-wont-wake-up-my-quest/)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to avoid the 10min dark screens? Or the lockups? Disabling the darkening of the screen may help avoid the lockups.

Comment: landroni: I like the darkscreen and the lockups. But sometimes I dont't get the login back when i want it. Not by pressing any key and not by moving the mouse. The display(s) stay black. Nothing happens. I need to restart.

Comment: What program is responsible for darkening the screen? XScreensaver? What DE do you use?

Comment: I don't know what programm is responsible. It's the standard programm from the settings panel. (Brightness and lock). What do you mean with DE?

Comment: Desktop Environment (Unity, Xfce, KDE, etc.)? And can you open a taskmanager, monitor when new applications pop up, then open the "standard programm from the settings panel" and check which process popped dup in the taskmanager.

Comment: Environment is Unity. I don't understand what you want me to do with the taskmanager. When the problem happens i can't do anything... Here is anotherone with the same problem: http://wafflesatnoon.com/2012/11/17/ubuntu-suspend-wont-wake-up-my-quest/ And by reading the comments there are much more peoples affected by that.

Comment: I have no experience with Unity, sorry. But if you want better help, do mention in your original question `Unity` and that link.

Comment: landroni: I have added Unity and the link to the Question. Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Have you looked in the the syslog for anything that might have been logged about the suspend/resume attempt? Run 'tail -f /var/log/syslog' after you have to restart the system. There might be a clue to the offending process.

Answer (score 1):

This [bug in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/781402) has some workaround which works for many users who have been using Ubuntu 13.10. Hope it works for you too.

Just follow these steps and try it once:

1. Copy the grub file first as backup for safety:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub_back
   ```

   taking the backup of original /etc/default/grub file, in case some error occurs we can get back to original state
2. Open **grub** file to edit:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   opening the file in gedit to make the changes.
3. Once file opened replace following line :

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to the line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
   ```

   <sub>**Note: The next line to the line mentioned above should be GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" not GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux". Just check for the differences.**</sub>

   save and close the file.
4. Update the grub and restart your system once:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   sudo reboot
   ```

Please reply if something goes wrong or you need any clarifications.

Comment: Thank you Kumar. I will try that and see if it happens again. This will take a while, because it not happens everytime. Thank you.

Comment: @rechengehirn: yes of course. Now I'm also willing to know whether it works for you or not, since it worked for many users. :)

Comment: Hi @Saurv Kumar. Today my computer didn't wakeup again. So this solution seems to be no help in my case. I have the feeling, that it has to do with usb. I try to add a non usb keyboard now. Perhaps that works.

Comment: @rechengehirn: I just wanted to test whether it works for you or not. Never mind have you tried [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361547/ubuntu-freezes-crash-after-wake-when-upgraded-to-13-10/361706#361706)? Actually I selected the best option which helped others and suggested you here. I just want from you to go for this answer of mine and check for other options. User's for whom it worked also replied with comment. :)

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem on my laptop. The only way I could come out of the screen dimmed state was to use the <kbd>FN</kbd> + "Screen" key on my laptop. In my case (on an Acer laptop), it was <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>.  Strangely enough, it comes back on as soon as I hit the <kbd>FN</kbd> key, but it won't come on if I move the mouse, touch the touchpad, press any keys, etc.  Pressing the <kbd>FN</kbd> key was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score -2):

Install the latest proprietary graphics driver on your PC.

At the moment to avoid restarts I would just disable the screen lock in the options.

PS: please give more details about your computer, OS version, graphics card, etc. The more the better

Comment: Hi Brask. I have a AMD HD 7950 grapics card with the 13.10 driver.

Comment: Hi have now installed the amd 13.12 driver (Had to patch it for the  3.11.0-15-generic kernel. But still the same problem.