# Ubuntu 12.04 not working after suspend

Tags: 12.04, suspend

when trying to run my Laptop after suspend .

I have a black screen and nothing work. keyboard,mouse,touch bad .

My PC : Laptop Dell Inspiron 15 R

Ram :4 GB

graphic Card :Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A]

any help

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, swap and ram matters only for hibernation, not suspend. Ahmed, try to see if this answer helps you: http://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395 .Otherwise, yuo really need to edit your question adding details (type of PC, graphic card/drivers, etc.)

Comment: Romano,I tried every thing in this post. but no new .

Comment: Try to see if there is some hint in the file `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` --- maybe an error or device that got stuck. Are you using open-source drivers for the graphic card or the proprietary ones (fglrx)?

Comment: pm-suspend.log file content 

`/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend suspend suspend: success.
Thu Apr  3 15:51:07 EET 2014: performing suspend
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00
commandline parameters: 
Thu Apr  3 16:39:13 EET 2014: Running hooks for suspend.
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change suspend suspend:`

Comment: Sorry, no idea (BTW, it is much better to add info to the question --- formatting in comments is quite limited).

Comment: There is a bug that seems relevant here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1214287 and it seems that that laptop has problems even in Windows: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3524/t/19496673.aspx --- I advise you the report a bug / add to the existing one and try to help developers to fix it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 0):

**Actually there is a bug which you can find in Launchpad.net**

Best thing is that there is also a patch through which you can solve this issue.

Follow these steps hope it works for you also:

Open terminal and execute these steps:

**1 - Backup old settings**

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub_back
```

**2 - Open file to edit**

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

**3 - Replace the line**

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force"
```

**4 - Save the file Ctrl+S and close Ctrl+Q**

Note: The next line to the line mentioned above should be GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" not GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"

**5 - Now execute following command to update the grub**

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Re-start your system once.**

Note: If you have trouble in brightness also and above method doesn't fix it then you can test by adding these lines in place I mentioned above.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor pcie_aspm=force"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pcie_aspm=force"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
```

Note: You have to do a sudo update-grub and a system restart every time you change the grub file

Different system would need different options, if any of the option works, I request to mention that in the comment.

**6 - Edit/create the file**

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt
```

**7 - copy and paste this code and save**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Switch to a VC before suspending and back after resume

case "$1" in
        resume|thaw)
            chvt 7
        ;;
        suspend|hibernate)
            chvt 1
        ;;
esac
```

**8 - make it executable:**

```
chmod 755 /etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt
```

**sources:**
https://askubuntu.com/a/387676/265172
and
https://askubuntu.com/a/361706/265172

Comment: now ubuntu working after suspend, but I have another problem because of using this Command `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`.. My Graphic Driver Not working

Comment: run $ sudo aticonfig --initial