# System freeze after waking up from sleep (suspend)

Tags: ati, 14.04, radeon, fglrx

I had a heating problem lately after I've been using the xorg driver for the Intel APU (Integrated graphics card) so I upgraded to fglrx proprietary driver.

But then I faced another problem, whenver I wake up my laptop after being suspended, it freezes. In rare cases I can move the mouse a little bit but it's just for 2-3 seconds, and it freezes again. I have to hard-reset it then.

My graphics card is **Radeon HD 7730m**. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you look at this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/361547/ubuntu-freezes-crash-after-wake-when-upgraded-to-13-10 ?

Comment: Yes and I've tried multiple combinations of these parameters. I can't say I tried them all but none of what I tried worked. Also the question is about an older kernel, driver and xorg system so may be it can't answer my question. Is there a way I can pinpoint what parameter could I possible need instead of tiral-and-error using numerous parameters ?